# Email submit through Mailchimp returning error, Javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am hoping this is a simple issue.  I am using the Mailchimp API to submit a simple email signup form from my website.  I am trying to learn javascript right now, so I am trying to do the httprequest and callback without jQuery.  Basically, I am trying to convert this jQuery sample I found online to vanilla Javascript.  But there is something (several things?) wrong with my javascript that I don't understand.

**EDIT:** When the form is submitted, I am taken to the email-validate.php page, and show the following error object returned by MailChimp.

```
{"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Invalid Resource","status":400,"detail":"The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.","instance":"","errors":[{"field":"","message":"Required fields were not provided: email_address"},{"field":"email_address","message":"Schema describes string, NULL found instead"}]}
```

jQuery

[Found here](http://kovalent.co/blog/mailchimp-api-example/) (this actually throws an ajax(...).success is not a function error in the console but still submits the form, FWIW)

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('.mc-form').submit(function(e){

    //prevent the form from submitting via the browser redirect
    e.preventDefault();

    //grab attributes and values out of the form
    var data = {email: $('#mc-email').val()};
    var endpoint = $(this).attr('action');

    //make the ajax request
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: "json",
      url: endpoint,
      data: data
    }).success(function(data){
      if(data.id){
        //successful adds will have an id attribute on the object
        alert('thanks for signing up');
      } else if (data.title == 'Member Exists') {
        //MC wil send back an error object with "Member Exists" as the title
        alert('thanks, but you are alredy signed up');
      } else {
        //something went wrong with the API call
        alert('oh no, there has been a problem');
      }
    }).error(function(){
      //the AJAX function returned a non-200, probably a server problem
      alert('oh no, there has been a problem');
    });
  });
});
```

My Javascript (that doesn't work)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("mc-form", function submit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = {"email": document.getElementById("mc-email").value};
        var endpoint = document.getElementById("mc-form").getAttribute('action');

        function formSubmit(callback){
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (request.readyState === 4) {
                      if (request.status === 200) {
                        //Parse returned string into an object, then pass the object to the callback function.
                        var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                        callback(response);
                      } else {
                   console.log('JSON request error');
                        }
                    }
                }
            request.open("POST", endpoint , true);
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.send(data);
        }
        function formResponse(response){
            if(response.id){
            //successful adds will have an id attribute on the object
            alert('Thank you for signing up for Launch Alerts!');
          } else if (response.title == 'Member Exists') {
            //MC wil send back an error object with "Member Exists" as the title
            alert('You are already signed up for Launch Alerts!');
          } else {
            //something went wrong with the API call
            alert('Something went wrong. Please resubmit the form!');
          }
        }
        formSubmit(formResponse);
    })
});
```

My html

```
<form class="mc-form" method="POST" action="./email-validate.php">
    <h2 class="launch-alerts">Never miss a launch with Launch Alerts</h2>
    <label for="mc-email">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mc-email" name="mc-email" autofocus="true" required/>
    <input type="text" value="pending" id="status" name="status" hidden/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It uses a php file to validate and submit the form, as can be seen on the link above. The html and php work to submit the form when using the jQuery script, but not my javascript, which means there is something wrong with my script, but I am too new with javascript to fully understand what it is I am trying to do, and what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

EDIT 2:

The PHP code (copied directly from [here](http://kovalent.co/blog/mailchimp-api-example/)

```
<?php
//fill in these values for with your own information
$api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$datacenter = 'xxxxx';
$list_id = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$status = 'pending';
if(!empty($_POST['status'])){
    $status = $_POST['status'];
}
$url = 'https://'.$datacenter.'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$list_id.'/members/';
$username = 'apikey';
$password = $api_key;
$data = array("email_address" => $email,"status" => $status);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$api_key");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: What's the error in the browser console?

Comment: I am not getting errors in the console (yet).  The request is being sent, but mailchimp is returning an error.  {"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Invalid Resource","status":400,"detail":"The resource submitted could not be validated. For field-specific details, see the 'errors' array.","instance":"","errors":[{"field":"","message":"Required fields were not provided: email_address"},{"field":"email_address","message":"Schema describes string, NULL found instead"}]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data argument to `request.send()` must be a URL-encoded string, you're passing an object. jQuery does this conversion automatically for you; when you do it yourself, you have to do that yourself as well.

```
var data = "email=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("mc-email").value);
```

You're also not adding your submission function to the form's `submit` event correctly. It should be:

```
document.getElementById("mc-form").addEventListener("submit", function submit(e){
```

Comment: Ok.  I tried this and it returns the same error.  This leads me to believe that I am still sending the wrong information.

Comment: Edited my question to show the error that is returned from Mailchimp

Comment: There must be abother problem in your PHP script when it calls the MailChimp API.

Comment: @Barmar I think it's just the missing url parameter "email"

Comment: I added the php.  I know very little about php and server side code, but I think the php is turning "email" into "email_address" before sending?

Comment: @user2415266 URL parameters go in `$_GET`, he's using `$_POST`.

Comment: @ncox85 What happens if you put a hard-coded email into the PHP script instead of using `$_POST['email']`?

Comment: @Barmar That works.  My callback doesn't fire, but the email is successfully submitted.  I am taken to the email-validate.php and shown the raw json data returned by Mailchimp.

Comment: The second line of your Javascript is wrong. See my updated answer.

Comment: This didn't fix it until I figured out the biggest and dumbest error I made. You guys are going to kill me.  'mc-form' was a class in my html, not an ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can add URL Parameters manually to the URL:

```
var endpoint = document.getElementById("mc-form").getAttribute('action') +
               "?email=" + document.getElementById("mc-email").value;
```

And then only do

```
request.send();
```

without the data in it.

Comment: Tried it several different ways, but it doesn't work.